# Understanding Wordpress Development

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

I have come across a wonderful portfolio website https://dogstudio.co/ while I was looking for examples of design. Upon exploring the source-code, it was apparent that this was a wordpress website after all.

What I don't understand is how and why does it not have the typical wordpress directory architecture.
For example, this is the URL to their CSS file, https://dogstudio.co/app/themes/portfolio-2018/static/css/main.css.

A typical wordpress website would have something like this, https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/theme_name/style.css (the **wp-content and wp- prefixed** directories) as a general rule of thumb for making wordpress themes.

So was it made using a framework? I really need to understand this.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing fancy to scratch the brain to understand it. You can say the most common way to implement the stylesheet is:

https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/theme_name/style.css

BUT WordPress docs not saying the theme style must comes from the theme directory. You can give any path of style ( including CDN ) from anywhere BUT IT SHOULD BE ACCESSIBLE.

Like

https://xyz/app/themes/portfolio-2018/static/css/main.css

https://samedomain/some-directory/themes/portfolio-2018/static/css/main.css

For more information, take a look at the **$src** option. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/